# I am unable to save the users input and add it to the table in the textFieldShouldRetrun function to a table in Xcode and I can't work out why

Tags: ios, swift, input, tableview, textfield

I've been trying for ages to get the user's input to save and add to the table so it can be used as a to do list but I am unable to. I've tried searching on here but nothing has helped me. Here is my whole code. This is actually my first time using Xcode and Swift so there may be some obvious mistake that I've missed. The problem is in the beginning of the textFieldShouldReturn function (sorry I haven't explained this well!)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return todos.count
    }


    struct todo {
        var text: String
        var isDone: Bool
    }
// this is the problem area:

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let t = todo(text: textField.text!, isDone: false)
        todos.append(t)        
        tableView.reloadData()
        textField.text = ""
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    var todos = [todo]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


  // the rest

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        var todo = todos[indexPath.row]
        todo.isDone = !todo.isDone
        todos[indexPath.row] = todo
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)


    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let id = "todo-cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id, for: indexPath)
        let todo = todos[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = todo.text
        if todo.isDone {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let t = todo (text:"clean my room", isDone: false)
        todos.append(t)

    }
}
```

Comment: *"(code starts here dont know why it won't show up in the grey box)"* - FYI - along the top the editor are some buttons, one looks like `{ }`, highlight you code section and tap it, it will automatically indent it (4 spaces), or if it's a one line or short block, indent it by 4 spaces

Comment: What input are you talking about? What is the actual issue with the code you posted? There is clearly some missing code and details in your question.

Comment: sorry about not specifying the question I'm new to this!  I'm having a problem with the textFieldShouldReturn function, the first two lines aren't doing their job - they're supposed to save the users input in the text field and then save it to the table but its just not working

Comment: "not working" isn't enough of a description. In what way exactly isn't the code working? Is `textFieldShouldReturn` being called at all?

Comment: I'm sorry again I'm not being specific enough - I think I understand fully now what the problem is - tableView.reloadData() - gives me a fatal error about how it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I've looked it up but I can't seem to find anything that solves it. sorry again, and the function is being called it just stops when the fatal error occurs

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, assuming that's all of it, you're not assigning the delegates anywhere. In `viewDidLoad()` you have to set your UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource and UITextFieldDelegate.

```
tableView.delegate = self
tabelView.dataSource = self
textField.delegate = self
```

Comment: What is `textField`? There's nothing in the code showing a text field being created. And how do you know the table view data source isn't set? It may have been set in the storyboard. The question makes no mention of the table not showing its data.

Comment: There's multiple references to `textField` and ViewController class is a UITextFieldDelegate. The question doesn't even say what her problem is exactly, but giving her a possible solution is more helpful than complaining about her question.

Comment: The only reference to `textField` are in the delegate method and that's not where you would set the delegate. And no one is complaining about the question. People are asking for clarification so good answers can be provided.

Comment: sorry I haven't specified the question properly its because I'm pretty confused with whats happening, it's my first time using Xcode so I'm pretty lost the main problem is the textFieldShouldReturn function as the first part is supposed to save the users input and display it onto the table but it won't happen, sorry again for the bad question!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, it's crashing at the line `tableView.reloadData()`?